# Angular attach extra values to a clicked link

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way i could attach the values from the linksList( for ex: gameID) and get them in the click event? Or is my whole approach totally wrong?

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in linksList">
  <li ng-click="onClickLink($event)">
    <a href="#">{{ item.gameName }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
.controller('LinkCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.linksList = [
        {
            gameID: 'l2',
            gameName: 'Lineage 2'
        },
        {
            gameID: 'h4',
            gameName: 'Heroes of Might and Magic IV'
        }
    ]

    $scope.onClickLink = function ($event) {
        console.log($event.target.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use onClickLink(item.gameId) no need of event, in controller use $scope.onClickLink = function (gameid) {
        console.log(gameid)
    }

Comment: didn't get you. please elaborate.

Comment: @Sravan basically i want to build a list and for each clicked item and i have to send some data to via a $http.post request. The data for each clicked link must contain for example gameID, gameName. How can i get both gameId and gameName inside the console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like this.

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in linksList">
  <li ng-click="onClickLink(item.gameID)">
   <a href="#">{{ item.gameName }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

And inside your controller

```
$scope.onClickLink = function (gameID) {
    console.log(gameID)
}
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer -> console.log(gameId) to console.log(gameID)

Comment: They are both good answers, i will accept this one, because you can see the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just send item in click event like `ng-click="onClickLink(item)` so that you can access whole data related to that list item.check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GYipJUtk1Aj8wdTigJkx?p=preview).click any list item so that you will alerted about id and name here

Answer (score 1):

Here is your requirement to send the selected data to the controller and making a post request.

**You can use the argument sent from the function call in the view in the post http request.**

The method will be something like this,

**Function with post request using the data:**

```
$scope.onClickLink = function (item) {
    alert(item.gameID)
    $http.post('/somefile', {'gameID':  item.gameID})
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.data = "Something went wrong";
    });
}
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<ul ng-repeat="item in linksList">
  <li ng-click="onClickLink(item)">
    <a href="#">{{ item.gameName }}</a></li>
</ul>
  </body>

</html>


</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbokLj4u/)

Comment: Thanks! I had the rest of the code for posting, just didn't know how to add the object in there. And i will be right back with my next stupid question xDD